# Is it possible to change somehow color profile in css

Tags: css

I wonder, is it possible to change somehow color profile in css for the site. 
As I understand by default standard browser leverage [sRGB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB) color profile.

But how I could change it to another one (e.g. profile to [Adobe RGB (1998)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_RGB_color_space)).

PS
The goal is - slice correctly *psd* to html and css. PSD uses Adobe RGB (1998), so if I use same colors values on the site they are different from original colors from psd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS has no means of adjusting color profiles.
You have to convert color profiles in Photoshop and use sRGB.

Answer (score 2):

not sure you should be worrying about this:
https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12557/whats-the-difference-between-adobe-rgb-and-srgb-and-which-should-i-set-in-my-ca

"sRGB is best for images view on screen, Adobe RGB is best for printing."

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to use the `eyedropper` tool in photoshop and take the RGB or hex values of the color that you want to select. Under the CSS, just paste that color code that you want. Thats it.

If you have the psd document as `sRGB` or `adobe RGB`, you will get the color that you want and get the color profile from your psd itself.

Comment: If we do so, than we'll have different colors on the web and psd.

Comment: If your psd document has an `sRGB` profile, the hex color you get from the eyedropper will be the same that you want on web, that color, you will paste in your CSS too. You can practically check.

Comment: Then too use eyedropper to catch the hex value and integrate in your css. The output of PSD and web will be same, as hex value will generate the color code that you are picking up from your psd.

Comment: Adobe RGB includes colors that do not exist in sRGB (bright green for example). Hex values copied from an Adobe RGB color will not result in the same color in sRGB -- they'll be much more faded.